# Symfony 2 - Unzip a ZIP file & upload folder permissions

Tags: php, macos, symfony, permissions, file-permissions

I have a Symfony 2 project with an upload folder (uploads works well). I'm creating a ZIP file after the upload which I put inside the same folder as the uploaded file (so the archive is **created from the PHP script**).

But i cannot extract the archive afterwards under MAC OS. The error is the following ("100" beeing a folder inside the upload folder):

[image: Unzip error]

What does that mean in MAC OS ? I suspect this is a directory permission issue. If i move and try to extract the ZIP on my Desktop it does not work either. I don't know in which direction to look. I've noticed if i try to do the same thing on another PHP project on which i DIDN't mess with the permissions required when installing symfony, the script and ZIP extraction works...

Updates :
Folder/files permissions :
[image]

Sudo unzip result :
[image]

Any ideas ? Thanks in advance,

Comment: Could you please check the permissions and owners of the directory and the zip file ("ls -l")? Is there any way you run the unzipping using "sudo" on the command line ?

Comment: @Answers_Seeker Updated question with the informations.

Comment: This forum thread may treat your problem: [error thread](askubuntu.com/questions/54904/unzip-error-end-of-central-directory-signature-not-found). The command "jar xvf COCR2_100.zip" got more votes. If you could compare the **md5sum** when you create the zipfile in your php script and the one you get when you downloaded it.

Comment: Yes, a MD5 checksum echoed in the 2 projects are exaclty the same...

Comment: Got that working. Thanks for the MD5 trick, it helped me find where i screwed up.

Comment: You got to learn some things about Zip archives in general by trying to debug yourself also (checksum, zip-time and download time differences, etc...). Bravo pour avoir réussi à te debug seul ;)

Comment: Yep. It's funny how to post on SO even if someone does not give you the answer straight out of the box helps you think out of the box. Makes you feel confortable... Merci en tout cas !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working ! **NEVER trim() a ZIP file contents** before saving it somewhere on your server. It seems to corrupt the archive.